# Search a tree with three nodes?

Tags: java, search, binary-tree

I can't seem to figure this out

My tree nodes have the following 3 string fields and 3 node fields which are left, middle and right.

This is what I have

```
public TreeNode findNode(String name) {
    TreeNode pointer = this.getRoot();
    if (!(name.equals(pointer.getName()))) {
        pointer = pointer.getLeft();
        findNode(name);
        pointer = pointer.getMiddle();
        pointer = pointer.getRight();
    }
    return pointer;
}
```

I see that the problem is that I keep reseting the pointer to root with every iteration but I think that findNode should only intake string as it's parameter. I don't see a way to do this.

Comment: If it is a binary tree, it should only have `getLeft()` and `getRight()`.  You should go to left branch if `name` is less than `pointer.getName()` and to the right branch otherwise.  Also, in the inner statement, you should `return findNode(name)`.

Comment: If it is a regular tree, how are the nodes structured?  Random? Or is it that left < middle < right?

Comment: yep left < middle < right

Comment: How is it decided whether an element goes in the left, middle, or right subtree?

Comment: Not exactly sure. I think I'm supposed to start left and then do middle and then right

Comment: One obvious problem is that inside findNode you call findNode on the *current* node always, instead of on the left/middle/right node. To have a sensible kind of Tree, it must be properly defined in which of the child nodes you have to look (if the current node isn't already the one you need of course), otherwise you will search the complete Tree, making it totally useless: then you might as well use a List.

Comment: Additionally, you do actually take 3 steps down the tree in one findNode, as you're overwriting your pointer 3 times. And to start, your pointer always starts from this.getRoot(), which suggests it's the root of the tree. I'm afraid you should start over thinking about how this tree is supposed to work.