# How to search a tree with three children nodes?

Tags: java, search, tree, children

My tree nodes have the 3 string fields and 3 node fields which are left, middle and right.

One of the problems is that the method can only take string as a parameter

This is what I have

```
public TreeNode findNode(String name) {
    TreeNode pointer = this.getRoot();

    if (pointer.getName().equals(name))
        return pointer;
    if (pointer.getLeft() != null)
        pointer = pointer.getLeft();
    findNode(name);
    if (pointer.getMiddle() != null)
        pointer = pointer.getMiddle();
    findNode(name);
    if (pointer.getRight() != null)
        pointer = pointer.getRight();
    findNode(name);
    return null;

}
```

This causes a stack overflow error because I just keep setting the pointer to root. But I have to start somewhere and my only parameters for the method can be name. I can't seem to see how to do this.

Comment: Could it be that your method body should have more return statements? You see, you recursively call your find method; to then ignore its result; and always return null? And btw: you want to put { } around ANY block (so, always do that for if/then/else, for loops, while loops, whatever).

Comment: Well if I find the node with the name I return the pointer. Shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: Again: if one of your recursive calls "finds" the correct node and returns it; the result of that recursive call is **not used**. Meaning: it doesn't help to return a value in one place; when you ignore the returned result one layer above!

Comment: This looks suspiciously like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29528675/search-a-tree-with-three-nodes

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list as a parameter stack.

```
public TreeNode findNode(String name) {
    List<TreeNode> stack = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();
    stack.add(this.getRoot());
    while (!stack.isEmpty())
    {
        TreeNode node = stack.remove(0);
        if (node.getName().equals(name))
            return node;
        if (pointer.getLeft() != null)
            stack.add(node.getLeft());
        if (node.getMiddle() != null)
            stack.add(node.getMiddle());
        if (node.getRight() != null)
            stack.add(node.getRight());
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can remove from the end of the list instead of the front of the list if you want to search depth-first.

Comment: I can't use any Java API data structure classes. only arrays

Comment: If there is a maximum tree depth, then you can walk the tree in a similar manner using an array and an index into the array.  Using "List" just makes that easier.  This would require you to go depth-first though, as otherwise you will go out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Use an auxiliary method that takes in a `TreeNode` parameter in addition to the string:

```
public TreeNode findNode(String name) {
    return auxFindNode(this.getRoot(), name);
}

private TreeNode auxFindNode(TreeNode node, String name) {
    //perform your recursive traversal here
}
```

Your code as it stands will never work because you keep setting `pointer` to the root of the tree at the beginning of the method. So all your recursive calls start with the root of the tree.

If you prefer not to use another method, you can traverse the tree iteratively by using stack:

```
public TreeNode findNode(String name) {
    Stack<TreeNode> stack = new Stack<TreeNode>();
    TreeNode foundNode = null;


    while(!stack.empty() && foundNode == null) {
        TreeNode node = stack.pop();

        if(node.getName().equals(name)) {
            foundNode = node;
        } else {
            if(node.getLeft() != null) {
                stack.push(node.getLeft();
            }

            if(node.getMiddle() != null) {
                stack.push(node.getMiddle());
            }

            if(node.getRight() != null) {
                stack.push(node.getRight());
            }
        }            
    }

    return foundNode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you cannot change the signature of this function. Have a helper function that takes in two parameters, (Node and name) that you call with root and name.

Answer (score 0):

In all three cases (left, middle, right), you are calling `findNode(name)` but not for those objects, instead it is for `this`. That's why you get **stack overflow**.